# Is there any institution or report tracking academic fields in terms of funding (today and historically)?

Tags: funding

I am wondering if any trustworthy sources exist, which track funding trends across academic disciplines over time.

Sure, anyone can think of some anecdote about how *there's more money in robotics than in cultural anthropology* – but is there any concrete place to check the stats, on either a national or global scale?

Comment: Most national grant agencies (and probably the EU) publish their funding decisions, often in the aggregated form you are look for. You would perhaps have to compile the data across time periods, and of course, across different national grant agencies.

Answer (score 2):

Two platforms come to my mind.

First, [Dimensions](https://app.dimensions.ai/discover/grant) offers detailed data about grants and research funding - however, only the paid version would allow users to delve deeper into these data so as to treck trends over time (including at the level of countries, disciplines, topics, institutions or individual researchers).

Second, [wizdom.ai](https://www.wizdom.ai/) seems to allow you to track funding allocations by research topics for free, including a list of "top funders", a "funders analysis" containing the amount of money allocated, a topic wordcloud, and a timeline.

Here is an example for Robotics: https://www.wizdom.ai/topic/robotics/funders/20903754, and a screenshot of how it looks like:

[image: wizdom.ai data on funding in the realm of Robotics (1/2)]

[image: wizdom.ai data on funding in the realm of Robotics (2/2)]